# File hosting to track total downloads of a PDF

Tags: pdf, file-sharing

I am looking for a web service that will allow me to upload a PDF and can track the number of times it is downloaded **regardless of the source**.  I am aware of Google Analytics event tracking on my site but the issue here is that I need to give the file path to a number of partner sites and would like a centralized place to view total downloads among all partners.  A breakdown of downloads by source would be awesome but not necessary.  I can't rely on getting numbers from all of the partners as some may not even have GA set up at all.

Does something like this exist?  Free is nice but would be willing to pay for an account if necessary.

Thanks.

Comment: There's these things called "access logs" which can be "analyzed" and provide "download counts".

Comment: thanks Marc - but lets say I a) don't want to host file on my server b) want to be able to give the partners the login credentials of the service in question so they can see total downloads too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up using bit.ly to to shorten the path to the PDF hosted on my server.  Gave the shortened url to the partners.  Bit.ly provides good click stats by simply adding a "+" to end of the shortened url so we could see results.

Comment: The only problem with this is that people may share the real URL over email/social apps/IM etc, thus breaking your download counting.

Comment: Good point.  Still the best solution I could come up with quickly.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried Ge.tt ? 
I believe it shows number of times your files has been downloaded.