# How to track clicks on hosted PDF link without code

Tags: click-tracking

I have a few PDFs hosted online (not our company's website) that I am trying to track clicks from emails without code or redirecting from landing pages.

[File hosting to track total downloads of a PDF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12732105/file-hosting-to-track-total-downloads-of-a-pdf)

^ This question was helpful but the limitation with bit.ly is you can't track clicks to the same link separately or on a campaign basis.

Another thing to note is that the links to the hosted PDFs we have are the same except for a first name. Example:

"example.com/salesdocument_John.pdf" & "example.com/salesdocument_Lisa.pdf"

We pull in the first name with data so I need to be able to enter the link in the email copy with just the first name pulled in via "wildcard/token".

Thanks!

Comment: You said "not our company's website" -- but do you have access to the web server logs? Access logs would show you how many times the file has been accessed.

Comment: We are currently hosting them through our email marketing provider (Marketo), but it doesn't track the number of times it has been accessed unless you email the link through Marketo and we are currently sending the emails through a CRM system that doesn't track clicks how we need to. We don't plan to start sending the links out through Marketo. Thanks!